# saving a TCP audio stream to .wav

Tags: python, audio, tcp, stream, wave

I´m trying to capture an audiostream that is send over TCP.
It kind of works but I have a lot of noise and gaps inside the audiofile. I don't really know what is going wrong so maybe you can help me:

```
import socket,os, sys
import threading, wave, pyaudio

host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = '192.168.1.4'#  socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print(host_ip)
port = 2013

filename="test.wav"
CHANNELS=2
RATE=24000
frames = []
sample_format=pyaudio.paInt16
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def audio_stream():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
        socket_address = (host_ip,port-1)
        print('server listening at',socket_address)
        client_socket.connect(socket_address) 
        print("CLIENT CONNECTED TO",socket_address)
        data_start=b'\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x06\x00\xfd\x74\xfa\x03\x00\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        client_socket.sendall(data_start)
        print("Sent:     {}".format(data_start))
        i=0
        while True:
            try:
                data= client_socket.recv(1024*2)
                frames.append(data)
                
                i=i+1
                if i==1500:
                    data_stop=b'\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x08\x00\xce\xa7\x8a\x49\x00\x01\x05\x00'
                    client_socket.sendall(data_stop)
                    print("Sent:     {}".format(data_stop))
                    print(frames)
                    client_socket.close()
                    print('Audio closed')
            except socket.error as error_message:
                break
        
    with wave.open(filename,"wb") as sf:
                sf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
                sf.setsampwidth(3)
                sf.setframerate(RATE)
                sf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
                sf.close()      
                print("data saved")
    
    os._exit(1)
    
t1 = threading.Thread(target=audio_stream, args=())
t1.start()
```

I'm sending a  message "data_start" to start the audiostream on a testrack. I capture the tcp frame I get and stop the audiostream with the "data_stop" message. After that the captured frames will be saved into an wavefile.

Wavefile of the captured tcp stream:

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of noise, left and right of the burst there should be anything near silence. There are also a lot of gaps inside the signal that aren't in the expected signal. For better comparison I show you the expected signal:

[image: expected signal]

Am I missing frames or anything else?

Comment: if you can send stream then use small data and compare it with data which you receive. OR maybe stream has different `RATE` or other values - and when you write to file then it convert it.

Comment: I already tried different RATEs , 16k 24k ,44.1k,48k. I expected the best result at 48k, but as you see 24k is where I stayed. I changed the sample_format into Int32 and float, Int16 was best and what expected, so it has to be anything else.

Comment: When I print the frames I get somethin like this : [b'\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x07\x00RG\x94C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x04\n\x00meg\ ....] Compared to the payload I captured with wireshark, there are not only two digitx after the x like x01, yout can see that there ist also x00RG, thats the diffrent to the wireshark capture: [0x01, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xff, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x52, 0x47, 0x94, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14,]
So how can I make sure that i get the right frames ?

Comment: `hex(ord("R"))` gives `0x52` so `RG` is the same as `0x52, 0x47`. You could check what you get when you write and read it again.